# How to color wrapped lines with multiple color in html and js?

Tags: javascript, html, css, inline

I have this div element in witch I want to set different color for every wrapped line.

With  `cl.style.display = "inline"; Reacts = cl.getClientRects();`
I'm able to get top, left, right and bottom of every line

I then tried to set colors using

```
background: linear-gradient(...); and box-shadow:..;
```

so far without any success.

A little help would really be appreciated.

```css
.cl {
    width: 500px;
    height: fit-content;
    min-height: 18px;
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;

    display: inline-block;
    padding: 2px;
    white-space: pre-wrap;
    word-break: break-word;
}
```

```html
<div class="cl">aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa</div>
```

[what I want]

```
image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/w2WRY.png
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should achieve the effect you want by using the `repeating-linear-gradient` I define a variable in css to make it simple, but if it confuses you, you could directly write it.

*I doesn't apply the css you want, but I think it is very easy for your to achieve: )

```css
div {
  --spacing: 2em;
  line-height: var(--spacing);
  background-image: repeating-linear-gradient(red 0 var(--spacing), green var(--spacing) calc(var(--spacing) * 2), blue var(--spacing) calc(var(--spacing) * 3), transparent var(--spacing) calc(var(--spacing) * 4));
}
```

```html
<div>Stack Overflow is a question and answer website for professional and enthusiast programmers. It is the flagship site of the Stack Exchange Network,[4][5][6] created in 2008 by Jeff Atwood and Joel Spolsky.[7][8] It features questions and answers on a
  wide range of topics in computer programming.[9][10][11] It was created to be a more open alternative to earlier question and answer websites such as Experts-Exchange. Stack Overflow was sold to Prosus, a Netherlands-based consumer internet conglomerate,
  on 2 June 2021 for $1.8 billion.[12]</div>
```

Comment: Cool!! this looks promising... is there any way so that I could get the last line color to fit the text (width) on it: image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/w2WRY.png

Comment: @DJcoder, just kind confused by `get the last line color to fit the text (width) on it`, what do you want to achieve?

Comment: I guess it is best explained in this image: https://imgur.com/a/2GojeoB

Comment: @DJcoder, I think probably not if using `background-image: repeating-linear-gradient` background-image: repeating-linear-gradient` since `background-image: repeating-linear-gradient` assign the background-color based on the width of the element, not the text. But I am trying to think if there is alternative solution.

Comment: @DJcoder, I ask an question as well regarding to this problem. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70714605/what-will-be-an-alternative-solution-for-background-image-repeating-linear-gradBut I think maybe no way instead of using for loop (too messy), do you want that answer?

Comment: using loop... if u mean enclosing the text in an additional inline element, I know how to do it. But a lot of thanks to you  repeating-linear-gradient is going to be very helpful!:)

Comment: @DJcoder, just saw someone post an answer in my question and it does work. Check it:)